# Why don't I have an overflow error when I pass an extremely large double to printf(); to output it in exponential format in C?

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to understand how printf(); behaves in this particular situation. I'm putting an extremely large double (which by my logic surpasses the max value of double) and output it in the exponential form, but it doesn't overflow for some reason...

For example, if I do this in my code:
`printf("%5.6e\n", 554444444493333333333333333333333332222222222222222222999999999999999999999999999999999999996342.69111999999999999999999999999911);`
the output will be:
`5.544444e+95`
By all means, there should've been an overflow! Why doesn't it overflow?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that `DBL_MAX` is `1.79769e+308`. Much bigger!

Comment: What exactly did you expect?
https://godbolt.org/z/G678YzoEh

Comment: Losing precision is not the same as an overflow. Floating point types do rounding all the time.

Comment: If you had put the suffix`f` after that number (to make it a `float`) then the compiler would object with (MSVC) *"constant too big"*, because `FLT_MAX` is only `3.40282e+38`. Now, if you assign your large number to a `double` variable and then copied to a `float` variable and *then* print it, the output (MSVC) is `inf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact definition of `double` varies by environment, but there's a good chance you're using [double-precision IEEE floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). I'll be assuming that's the case in this Answer.

---

There are two concepts you need to be aware of: range and precision.

The *range* of doubles is around -1.8e+308 to +1.8e+308. +5.5e+95 fits comfortably within that range. So no overflow occurs (i.e. you don't get +infinity).

Doubles have 53 bits of *precision*,<sup>[1]</sup> which is just over 16 digits of precision. That's just a tiny fraction of the precision required to store the number in question accurately.

```
Desired number
554444444493333333333333333333333332222222222222222222999999999999999999999999999999999999996342.69111999999999999999999999999911
|--------------|  16 digits
554444444493333341401218537659960350559705017202995895614073404165347365295786488352162172633088
Stored number
```

The range is rarely a limiting factor. But a lack of precision is a very common problem. For example, 1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 6/10, 8/10 and 9/10 are all periodic numbers in binary (like 1/3 in decimal), so each would require infinite precision (and thus memory and time) to store accurately as a floating point number. That's why floating point numbers are very rarely exactly the desired number.

```
$ perl -Mv5.14 -e'say sprintf q{%1$.1f: %1$.100g}, $_ / 10 for 1 .. 10'
0.1: 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
0.2: 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
0.3: 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
0.4: 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
0.5: 0.5
0.6: 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
0.7: 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
0.8: 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
0.9: 0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
1.0: 1
```

---

1. 52 for subnormals (extremely tiny  numbers).